# Chart of Item Types in VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to convert a small team to the benefits of using TFS with Visual Studio Online. I've created a custom process and custom work item type. I've also adde a few 'custom' states for items (eg: 'In Test').

Is it possible to create a query/chart similar to below, with a count of each item type - as below?

[image]

Comment: Do you solve this issue with soja's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new query to retrieve necessary work items
2. Go to your team project Home page (e.g. Home=>Overview)
3. Click Edit Dashboard=>Add Widget

[image]

4. Select Char for Work Items=>Add

[image]

5. Click Configure to configure this widget
6. Select corresponding Query
7. Select Chart type (e.g. Column)
8. Select State in Group by list

[image]

9. Click Save

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VSTS supports [dashboards](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/dashboards) that you can easily add widgets to. You can add dashboards on the Home tab by clicking `+ New` in the upper right, and edit with the checkmark in the lower right. Have a look at the [Chart for Work Items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/widget-catalog#chart-wit-widget) widget. Given a query of work items, it supports various chart visualization that you can configure and show.